# Each cell of a $100 × 100$ table is painted either black or white and all the cells adjacent to the border of the table are black.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Each cell of a $100 × 100$ table is painted either black or white and all the cells adjacent to the border of the table are black. Can we color the rest of a table so that every $2 × 2$ square there are cells of both colours?

---

This problem is related to [Prove there exists $2\times 2$ checkerboard-colored square in a $100\times 100$ table colored black and white.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203607/prove-there-exists-2-times-2-checkerboard-colored-square-in-a-100-times-100)

When I was solving related problem I tryed to draw such $n\times n$ table for $n\in\{3,4,5,6\}$.

For 3 and 5 (and any odd number) we can just do concentric rings.

I could'n draw it for $n=4$ and also for $n=6$.

So is such a coloring even possible for $n=100$ or any even $n$?

Comment: For $3$ and $5$ (and any odd number) you can just do concentric rings.  You should clarify your post to say you can do them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution for $n=12$, that you can adapt for any (odd or even) $n>4$. Draw a checkerboard, but make sure the four inner corners stay white.

[image]